# How can I find out which RESTEasy version is being used in Wildfly 1x.x.x

Tags: maven, jboss, version, wildfly, resteasy

I am working on updating from an older version of Jboss to Wildfly.
As in my poms I declared Resteasy `provided`, I was wondering how I can get to know which version is provided by the container, in order to update my declared version too.

By doing some search, I found that this should help: https://github.com/wildfly/boms/tree/18.0.1.Final. Unfortunately, by checking out the bom, I am still not able to understand which version of RESTeasy is being used.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this last on a wildfly 10.1 so maybe this is a bit outdated, but there you will find the used version in the modules directory of wildfly under

```
<INSTALL_PATH>/modules/system/layers/base/
```

There is a path to most libraries that are supplied by wildfly so you can just look them up there.

Resteasy is hidden under

```
<INSTALL_PATH>/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/
```

You have to look into one of the library subdirs (like e.g. "resteasy-jaxrs"), where you will find a main sub dir with the actual library:

```
<INSTALL_PATH>/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/main/
```

In this directory you will find the actual libraries (including versions) and a file called modules.xml that describes them.

Version of resteasy on wildlfy 10.1 was "3.0.19.Final".

EDIT: I just verified that on wildfly 18.0.1 it is all the same! Resteasy version there is 3.9.1.Final.

Answer (score 3):

There's also an easy way if you want to check first the RESTEasy version for the Wildfly you're using. Just go to the Wildfly repository on github. For each version, there's a pom.xml. Under that file you'll see versions. You can check there as to what version it is using. Sample: [Wildfly 25 RestEasy version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOVrJ.png)